# Why SQL transaction not getting Rollback

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to rollback a transaction if the sum of enrollment for certain classes is over 50. For some reason, even though my if statement equates to true (the sum of the courses is 60) this still ends up deleting the courses.

Any ideas?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
DELETE FROM Course WHERE Term = 'C'
    IF (SELECT SUM(Enrollment) FROM Course WHERE Term = 'C') > 50
    BEGIN;
        THROW 50002, 'Total Enrollment Greater Than 50... Rolling Back Transaction...', 1;
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION T1;
    END;
COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
```

Comment: did you try put COMMIT in ELSE ?

Comment: why are you executing delete query before checking the condition?

Comment: Couldn't I also create a Trigger After a Delete that would check the same status?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you executing delete query before checking the condition?

If you Delete records from `Course` table Where condition satisfy `Term = 'C'`, then SELECT query `IF (SELECT SUM(Enrollment) FROM Course WHERE Term = 'C') > 50` never going to satisfy and not rollback.

Comment: Ahh so as soon as a transaction hits a true statement it breaks out?

Comment: @Dunnage No. But if you delete all rows and then count them you will find that there is nothing to count. Of course the count should be first.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the help.